# Edit using Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to edit a category. This is done by clicking on the edit button and a popup being displayed. The Java code is...

```
@GetMapping(path = "/category/edit/{id}")
    public String showEditUserCategoryForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Optional<UserCategory> selectedCategory = userCategoryService.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("newCategory", new UserCategoryForm());
        model.addAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory.get());
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/category/edit/{id}/complete")
    public String submitEditedUserCategoryForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                               @ModelAttribute("newCategory")
                                               @Valid UserCategoryForm userCategoryForm,
                                               @SessionAttribute("selectedCategory")
                                                           UserCategory selectedCategory,
                                               @SessionAttribute User user,
                                               BindingResult bindingResult,
                                               Model model) {
        userCategoryForm.setName(selectedCategory.getName());
        String newName = userCategoryForm.getName();
        userCategoryService.updateCategoryNameById(newName, selectedCategory.getId());
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }
```

The HTML code for the popup is...

```
<div id="ex4" class="modal">
        <h3 class="display-4">Update Category</h3>
        <form th:action="@{/category/edit/}" th:object="${newCategory}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="name">Category Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                       th:field="*{name}"
                       placeholder="Category Name"
                       class="form-control"
                       aria-describedBy="Enter category name" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                Update category name
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And to edit...

```
<a class="mdi mdi-pencil" th:href="@{/category/edit/{id} (id=${category.id})}"
                 href="#ex4" rel="modal:open"></a>
```

Problem is I don't know whether to use #ex4 or the edit link in the above anchor tag. Also, the form action, I want the ID of the category as that's what's in the controller, but it doesn't allow that. Please advice what changes I need to do and any other code improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you need to update in your code. But before that let me clarify something about modals.

Modals are clientside components, which means there is no request sent to the server for showing/closing the modals. That said, they are always part of a parent page and the parent page is served from the server.

Let me list down the steps involved in solving this question:

1. Parent page containing modal - Let's call it as category-detail.html (I am using Bootstrap 4 version here)

```
<h1>[[|${category.name}|]]</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategoryModal">
    Edit Category
</button>

<!-- Edit category modal  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editCategoryModal" tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editCategoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editCategoryModalLabel">Edit Category</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form th:object="${category}" th:action="@{|/category/*{id}|}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="catName">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="catName"
                               placeholder="Category Name" name="name" th:value="*{name}">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Category</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

The above HTML has to be included in your Thymeleaf template. It shows the category detail with a button to edit the category in a modal.

2. Controller method to reach the category detail page:
   We need to add a controller method which will take a `categoryId` and populate the category detail in model object and return the template name to be rendered as shown below:

```
String categoryName = "Information technology";

@GetMapping("/category/{categoryId}")
public String category(@PathVariable Long categoryId, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.put("categoryId", categoryId);
    //try to get the category detail object from DB
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setId(categoryId);
    category.setName(categoryName);

    modelMap.put("category", category);
    return "category-detail";
}
```

3. Controller method to handle the form submit for editing category:
   In the HTML above we have seen that the `form` element is bound to the action `/category/${id}` and uses the HTTP Method `POST`. So we need to create a method in the controller to handle this URL:

```
@PostMapping("/category/{categoryId}")
public String categoryEdit(
    @PathVariable Long categoryId,
    @RequestParam(name = "name") String categoryName){

    log.info("Category Id {}, Category Name {}", 
        categoryId, categoryName);
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    //you can update the database here
    return "redirect:/category/"+categoryId;
}
```

So now you have the complete flow implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use something like that. This is what I did:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editUserModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editUserModalLabel">Edit user</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form th:action="@{/administration/appuser/update}" th:object="${userData}" method='POST'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userId" class="col-form-label">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userId" th:field="*{userId}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-form-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" th:field="*{userName}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-form-label">New passowrd</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}" id="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="active" class="col-form-label">Active</label>
                        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{active}" id="active">
                            <option value="0">Disabled</option>
                            <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the modal (popup) hidden by default

After that code I have a button that calls a JS function

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" th:user-name="${user.userName}" th:user-active="${user.active}" th:user-id="${user.userId}" th:onclick="editModalContent(this, this.getAttribute('user-name'), this.getAttribute('user-active'), this.getAttribute('user-id'))">
```

I used th:xxx as a way to define a variable and pass it to the JS function with this.getAttribute('xxx')

Then I have this simple function that read the params and set them in the modal so the user can use the form compilation directly in the popup

```
function editModalContent(t, username, active, id) {

    var modal = $('#editUserModal');

    // change modal content
    modal.find('#userId').val(id);
    modal.find('#userName').val(username);

}
```

Hope is what you are looking for

Regards,
Mohamad